# Passing numpy arrays in Cython to a C function that requires dynamically allocated arrays

Tags: python, c, arrays, numpy, cython

I have some C code that has the following declaration:

```
int myfunc(int m, int n, const double **a, double **b, double *c);
```

So `a` is a constant 2D array, `b` is a 2D array, and `c` is a 1D array, all dynamically allocated.  `b` and `c` do not need to be anything specifically before they are passed to `myfunc`, and should be understood as output information. For the purposes of this question, *I'm not allowed to change the declaration of `myfunc`.*

**Question 1:** How do I convert a given numpy array `a_np` into an array `a` with the format required by this C function, so that I can call this C function in Cython with `a`?

**Question 2:** Are the declarations for `b` and `c` below correct, or do they need to be in some other format for the C function to understand them as a 2D and 1D array (respectively)?

My attempt:

**myfile.pxd**

```
cdef extern from "myfile.h":
    int myfunc(int p, int q, const double **a, double **b, double *c)
```

**mytest.pyx**

```
cimport cython
cimport myfile
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

p = 3
q = 4
cdef:
    double** a = np.random.random([p,q])
    double** b
    double* c

myfile.myfunc(p, q, a, b, c)
```

Then in iPython I run

```
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
import mytest
```

The line with the definition of `a` gives me the error message `Cannot convert Python object to 'double **'`.   I don't get any error messages regarding `b` or `c`, but since I'm unable to run the C function at this time, I'm not sure the declarations of `b` and `c` are written correctly (that is, in a way that will enable the C function to output a 2D and a 1D array, respectively).

*Other attempts:* I've also tried following the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25972568/2944305), but this doesn't work with the double-asterisk type of arrays I have in the `myfunc` declaration.  The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20938498/2944305) does not apply to my task because I can't change the declaration of `myfunc`.

Comment: When you say "dynamically allocated", you mean *outside* `myfunc`? And since you're trying pass numpy arrays into `myfunc`, that is irrelevant and you just need to convert those numpy arrays into the suitable argument format (double and single pointers to double), correct?

Comment: @Evert First of all, let me warn you that I'm not very knowledgable about C. I'm just trying to use `myfunc` to compute the arrays `b` and `c` and I don't need them to be dynamically allocated or anything special.  I only called them "dynamically allocated" because that's the format I thought the double and single pointers to double necessitated.  In short, yes, you are correct.

Comment: Using `double**` doesn't match well with numpy. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27681814/proper-way-to-cast-numpy-matrix-to-c-double-pointer/ for some discussion.

Answer (score 12):

## Create a helper array in cython

To get a `double**` from a numpy array, you can create a helper-array of pointers in your *.pyx file. Further more, you have to make sure that the numpy array has the correct memory layout. (It might involve creating a copy)

### Fortran order

If your C-function expects fortran order (all x-coordinates in one list, all y coordinates in another list, all z-coordinates in a third list, if your array a corresponds to a list of points in 3D space)

```
N,M = a.shape
# Make sure the array a has the correct memory layout (here F-order)
cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=2, mode="fortran"] a_cython =
                         np.asarray(a, dtype = float, order="F")
#Create our helper array
cdef double** point_to_a = <double **>malloc(M * sizeof(double*))
if not point_to_a: raise MemoryError
try:
    #Fillup the array with pointers
    for i in range(M): 
        point_to_a[i] = &a_cython[0, i]
    # Call the C function that expects a double**
    myfunc(... &point_to_a[0], ...)
finally:
    free(point_to_a)
```

### C-order

If your C-function expects C-order ([x1,y1,z1] is the first list, [x2,y2,z2] the second list for a list of 3D points):

```
N,M = a.shape
# Make sure the array a has the correct memory layout (here C-order)
cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=2, mode="c"] a_cython =
                         np.asarray(a, dtype = float, order="C")
#Create our helper array
cdef double** point_to_a = <double **>malloc(N * sizeof(double*))
if not point_to_a: raise MemoryError
try:
    for i in range(N): 
        point_to_a[i] = &a_cython[i, 0]
    # Call the C function that expects a double**
    myfunc(... &point_to_a[0], ...)
finally:
    free(point_to_a)
```

Comment: You have no idea how long I've been searching for this answer.  Thank you for posting it.  But where is `a_cython` defined?

Comment: `cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=2, mode="fortran"] a_cython =
                         np.asarray(a, dtype = float, order="F")`

Comment: Thanks I must have not scrolled over far enough on the SO app.

Comment: Very helpful answer, thanks +1! Note that the [Cython docs](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/memory_allocation.html) recommends using `PyMem_Malloc()` and `PyMem_Free()` instead of `malloc()` and `free()`.

Comment: Furthermore, using the more generic [typed memoryviews](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html) (e.g. `cdef [:,::1] a_view = np.ascontiguousarray(a)` instead of `cdef np.ndarray[.....] a_view = ...`) comes with improved readability and [other advantages](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/numpy.html). See also [this tutorial](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/numpy_tutorial.html) or [this (duplicate) post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64326339).

Answer (score 0):

Reply 1: You can pass NumPy array via Cython to C using the location of the start of the array (see code below).

Reply 2: Your declarations seem correct but I don't use this approach of explicit memory management. You can use NumPy to declare `cdef`-ed arrays.

Use

```
cdef double[:,::1] a = np.random.random([p, q])
cdef double[:,::1] b = np.empty([p, q])
cdef double[::1] b = np.empty(q)
```

Then pass `&a[0]`, the location of the start of the array, to your C function. The `::1` is to ensure contiguousness.

A good reference for this is Jake Vanderplas' blog: https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/08/memoryview-benchmarks/

Finally, typically one creates functions in Cython and calls them in Python, so your Python code would be:

```
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
import mytest
mytest.mywrappedfunc()
```

where `mywrappedfunc` is a Python (`def` and not `cdef`) function defined in the module that can do the array declaration show above.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this doesn't work... I get the following errors: `Cannot take address of memoryview slice` for the array `a`, `Cannot assign type 'double[:, ::1]' to 'double **'` for `b`, and `Cannot assign type 'double[::1]' to 'double *'` for `c`.

Comment: Yes, I replaced my cdef statements with the cdef statements you provided.

Comment: Hi, I understand my confusion. I use cythonized Fortran code, for which it works.
You are using in C a 2D array that is a 1D array of pointers to 1D arrays, whereas in Fortran you have a direct pointer to the start of the array as the argument.
Options: 1. Set at compile time all (except the first) dimensions of your C array. 2. Use a 1D array with manual "sub-indexing" of the data in C. 3. If you cannot change the C code, you must build the array as an "array of pointers to 1D arrays" at the Cython level and pass this instead. The syntax `&c[0]` should work, I just checked it.